# Quartz job excecuted at pool startup with StartAt()

Tags: quartz.net

I use [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) for a while now for repeating tasks and it works quite well. For some reason I needed to create a task that would run on two particular days. Here's the implementation I made:

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

IJobDetail jobWeekEnd = JobBuilderExtend.Create<CreateConsultationReplayJob>(() => new StandardContextProvider());
ITrigger triggerWeekend = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                        .WithIdentity("Foo", "Bar")
                                        .WithCronSchedule("0 0 9 ? * SAT-SUN")
                                        .ForJob(jobWeekEnd)
                                        .Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobWeekEnd, triggerWeekend); // WORKS WELL

var jobNonWorkingDay = JobBuilderExtend.Create<CreateConsultationReplayJob>(() => new StandardContextProvider());
var trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                             .WithIdentity("Foo2", "Bar")
                             .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2017, 04, 17, 09, 00, 00)))
                             .ForJob(jobNonWorkingDay)
                             .Build();
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobNonWorkingDay, trigger1);

var jobNonWorkingDay2 = JobBuilderExtend.Create<CreateConsultationReplayJob>(() => new StandardContextProvider());
var trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                              .WithIdentity("Foo3", "Bar3")
                              .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2017, 05, 01, 09, 00, 00)))
                              .ForJob(jobNonWorkingDay2)
                              .Build();
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobNonWorkingDay2, trigger2);
```

trigger1 and trigger2 seems to trigger not at the correct time but each time I recycle the pool, and randomly, the last occurrence was at 11:16:15.

Any clue about where I should dig?

Comment: Seems like you're using Quartz.NET, I edited your question to set the proper tag.

Comment: @walen thanks for update

Comment: Try to start your scheduler after scheduling your jobs.
1) scheduler.ScheduleJob(...) 
2) scheduler.Start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the date of the first scheduler was in the past (`new DateTime(2017, 04, 17, 09, 00, 00)`) and no `EndAt` was defined, the trigger was fire once at start-up. From this info, two options:

1. Set an ending value using `EndAt()` - quick and clean
2. Surround the initialization with a date check - non-trivial solution for next reader, but avoid an useless job registration.